# Getting random connection timeouts

Tags: timeout, pppoe

I've started having a weird problem with my internet connection.

The setup is PC/PS4 -> Router -> ISP (PPPoE)

Since more than a week I've started getting random connection timeouts. This is most noticeable when using Skype as I get random 1-2 seconds where I can't hear the others and they can't hear me and also in PS4 multiplayer games where I get lag for 1, 1-2 seconds after which everything goes back to normal for a while.

This happens randomly sometimes once after 15 minutes, other times once after 20 minutes, other times once after 30-40 minutes, etc.

To test this I've tried pinging 8.8.8.8 and looking for timeouts. Surely the ping timeouts are visible there also.
For some reason this seems to be happening only when I connect to my ISP trough the router (I have wired connection). If I put the ethernet cable in my laptop directly and connect from here using PPPoE I don't get these timeouts when pinging 8.8.8.8 but if I switch back and use the router they appear again.

The thing is that I even got a brand new router today and yet I have same issues, same random ping timeouts. And what's even weirder is that a friend who uses same ISP has exactly same issues (except ping timeouts are not at same time when I have them - as we both tried to do pings at same time and I don't get a timeout when he does and vice versa).

The issue is very weird and I have no idea what else to try as it's very annoying in multiplayer games and on Skype calls.

Anyone has any idea what could be the cause issue, why I get the timeouts when going trough the router (and as I said this happens on old router and also on brand new router that I got today - one is TPLINK TL-WDR4300 and the new one is DLINK ROUTER AC1750 DUAL-B GB [ DIR-86 ], and also happens to a friend on same ISP but different router)?

Comment: What laptop do you have?

Comment: MacBook Pro late 2013

Comment: 2013 Macbook Pro's don't have ethernet ports, so what are you using to connect to the network because it can't be plugged into the laptop "directly"

Comment: The thunderbolt ethernet adapter. http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD463LL/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter